# If events $A$ and $B$ are independent and equal to each other why is $P(A \cap (A\cup B)) = P(A)$

Tags: probability

When I tried drawing the Venn Diagram for this problem I came to the conclusion that
$$P(A\cap (A\cup B)) = P(A) - P(A\cap B), $$ since that was where I saw these two events overlapping, but according to the answer's key that is incorrect. I have also tried finding the solution by rearranging the expression  $P(A\cup (A\cup B) = P(A) + P(A\cup B) - P(A\cap (A\cup B)) $, therefore $$P(A\cap (A\cup B)) = P(A) + P(A\cup B) - P(A\cup (A\cup B)).$$ So if I could somehow understand how $P(A\cup (A\cup B))= P(A\cup B)$ that would fix my problem as well.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Consider the sets before you consider the probability. Since $A$ is contained within $A\cup B$, we have $A \cap (A\cup B) = A$.

Comment: For any two sets $~R~$ and $~S,~$ if $~R\subseteq S,~$ then $~R \cap S = R.~$ Further, $~A~$ is a subset of $~[ ~A \cup B ~].$

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent and $A=B$, then $P(A)$ is either $0$ or $1$.